# Postgresql server doesn't start

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu

[Ubuntu 16.04]
I installed postgresql 9.5 along with dependencies:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5 libpq-dev
```

When I want to run `psql` then I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

But `/var/run/postgresql/` is empty. When I restart posgresql everything appears to be fine:

```
$ /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
[ ok ] Restarting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.

$ /etc/init.d/postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since wto 2016-09-27 16:18:26 CEST; 1min 15s ago
  Process: 3076 ExecReload=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3523 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3523 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

but if check `ps aux` there is not such PID (why??)

Total reinstalation doesn't help at all. How can I fix it?

Edit:

I've just noticed that then type `/etc/init.d/postgresql force-reload` postgresql, systemctl are alive awhile and then are killed automatically

Besides systemctl returns

```
postgresql.service         loaded active exited    PostgreSQL RDBMS
● postgresql@9.5-main.service loaded failed failed    PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main
```

Why is it failed?

Comment: What's in the postgresql's log?

Comment: /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log is empty because the process doesnt start at all I guess

Comment: What happens when you run `service postgresql start`?

Comment: I dont get any output in console but service postgresql status returns the same outpuit like above in my question. Seems be fine but there is no such process

Comment: You can execute the following command to START the server manually:

    `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`- Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeh it seems bo working but how can I revert it to be able to run it as service like normally ? `service postgresql start`

Comment: Welcome to systemd. The "normal" way is now via `systemctl`. Did you read [`README.systemd`](https://sources.debian.net/src/postgresql-common/176/systemd/README.systemd/)? I'm guessing and the README doesn't explain fully, but you probably need to run `systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main.service`. `postgresql.service` is a do-nothing pseudo-target pulled in by the real init script and doesn't do anything by itself.

Comment: but why after fresh postgres installation postgresql@9.5-main.service is failing ? I don't want to create new cluster

Comment: @mike927 Check the journal for `postgresql@9.5-main.service`. And hope that it tells you. And no, I don't like this consistent hiding of important information :-/.

Comment: unfortunately `systemctl start postgresql@9.5.service` doesn't start a process as well. Still no "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" file